# Displaying GeometryCollection with one geometry in QGIS fails

Tags: qgis, geojson, geometrycollection

I have a problem with displaying simple geometrycollection with one multipolygon as a vector layer in qgis. When I import the geometry in qgis I cannot zoom to layer nor see labels and style.
Here is the link to data I want to show [GeometryCollection](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=34914&params=0)

I managed however to show the data in geojson.io and tried to convert to different formats (shapefile,csv) but converted files were empty.

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, after I converted the original data in geojson.io to geosjon format I got modified geojson with FeatureCollection type and I had to remove type GeometryCollection and geometries and treat multipolygon as a geometry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) with the `-explodecollections` flag to remove the GeometryCollection that is wrapping the multipolygon, like this:

```bsh
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -explodecollections -lco RFC7946=YES get_geojson_exploded.geojson get_geojson.geojson
```

The `-lco RFC7946=YES` flag suppresses a coordinate system definition, which your sample file did not have and which can cause problems with some tools (because the current spec for GeoJSON does not allow any CRS other than WGS84).

The output file is recognized by QGIS as a MultiPolygon layer.

Answer (score 0):

I used following [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command to fix the json - this removed nesting *GeometryCollection* features and created "flat" geojson. Maybe useful for someone with bigger files which cannot be just uploaded somewhere.

```
jq '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[.features[].features[].features[]]}' input.geojson > output.geojson
```

You may want to have different number of features[], I had 2 *Collection* levels in the file.